# What is the splash range for Jarate and Mad Milk?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-sniper, tf2-scout

The wiki doesn't seem to have much on the [two splash weapons](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Covering) in game, [Mad Milk](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Mad_Milk) and [Jarate](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Jarate), in terms of splash radius.

What's the splash radius on these two weapons in terms of units? Is the splash radius effected by anything else, including height thrown from, or the position landed? Is it a circular radius, or a spherical radius?

Comment: Presumably it's a sphere with a radius unaffected by any factors, assuming it's a type of explosion. That said explosions in TF2 used to be unrotating boxes, so...

Comment: My experience is that it's the same range as a rocket or sticky bomb explosion, but I don't have any data to back that up or make it an official answer.

Comment: Jarate's range is [stupidly large (youtube)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjSQVSeSh5o).  If I had a number I'd post an answer but I haven't found one - no one seems to know.

Comment: @Timtech The wiki isn't the end-all-be-all to information. If someone knew enough about how maps work, they could create a test map with a hammer unit ruler textured on the ground, and simply keep throwing jarate/mad milk until it soaked a bot. That'd definitely be credible enough for me to accept.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After doing some testing, I would guess that it's around 200 units. Jarate and Mad Milk seem to be the same, and neither distance nor height thrown from seem to matter. I think it's a sphere that results from it, but I can't be sure. It does require line of sight though. I'm not sure how to get unit counts. I took screenshots though if anyone wants to check my methods.

I started off just throwing Jarate until it wouldn't soak, and marking it with bullets:
[image]

Once I determined that, I switched to scout:
[image]
[image]

Then I tested the walls, where basically everything right of that ridge worked except the very upper-right corner:
[image]
[image]

Since Pyro's range is known, I started testing with him to guess the range:
[image]

I couldn't approximate it very well, so I started testing more. I noticed that Medic's range to start healing was the same as Pyro's range, but then I got lucky when I switched from Scout to Sniper because the Sniper bot spawned where I was testing with Pyro and Medic. I started throwing Jarate and noticed that it was basically the same as where I was throwing milk:
[image]

That means that it's basically half of the Pyro's range, [which is 384.](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Flame_Thrower#Damage_and_function_times) Half of that's roughly 200, although there's no way to be sure what kind of crazy splash formulas it uses for sure without Valve telling.

Comment: Line of sight?  You mean you have to be looking at them while they're getting hit?

Comment: @Zibboz: You have to be able to see where the jar explodes.